# Configuring a 7.1 Surround Sound USB Headset?

Tags: 12.10, sound, usb, headset

I recently purchased [G35 Surround Sound headset](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/g35-surround-sound-headset) from Logitech. I would like to enable 7.1 surround sound for it, but haven't been able to find a method that works. It works correctly under Windows 7 on the same machine, so I'm guessing there's a software setting somewhere I'm missing. <strike>Oddly, all sound only goes the left speaker at the moment as well.</strike> (It's back to stereo now...I don't think I changed anything.) So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

The G35 (and G930) are what is known as a virtual 7.1 headset. So Pulseaudio is correctly identifying it as a stereo headset, as it contains only two speakers - left and right.

Under windows, the driver does some trickery to make it seem as if the headset is 7.1, but it doesn't actually have the physical speakers.

So alas, you're out of luck with this headset. A true 5.1 headset (four speakers in each side) would allow you to enable 5.1 audio though.

Comment: It still SOUNDS like surround sound on Windows, though. Is there no way to recreate that effect on Ubuntu?

Comment: It does sound like surround, but it is emulated. In the end you only got two ears, so it should be possible to emulate it. ;) Sure it will never be as good as having distinct speakers.